# execve("/bin/sh", 0, 0); in a pipe

Tags: c, shell, pipe, freebsd, execve

I have the following example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char ** argv){
    char buf[100];

    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    gets(buf);
    printf("Hello \"%s\"\n", buf);

    execve("/bin/sh", 0, 0);
}
```

I and when I run without any pipe it works as it should and returns a `sh` promt:

```
bash$ ./a.out
Please enter your name: warning: this program uses gets() which is unsafe.
testName
Hello "testName"
$ exit
bash$
```

But this does not work in a pipe, i think I know why that is, but I cannot figure out a solution. Example run bellow.

```
bash$ echo -e "testName\npwd" | ./a.out
Please enter your name: warning: this program uses gets() which is unsafe.
Hello "testName"
bash$
```

I figure this has something to do with the fact that `gets` empties `stdin` in such a way that `/bin/sh` receives a EOF and promtly quits without an error message.

But how do I get around this (without modifying the program, if possible, and not removing `gets`, if not) so that I get a promt even though I supply input through a pipe?

P.S. I am running this on a FreeBSD (4.8) machine D.S.

Comment: ***NEVER*** use `gets`. It **always** opens a buffer overflow security hole.

Comment: I know ;) ... this is part of a buffer overflow attempt on a computer at the security lab at my university. Purely academic. =D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run your program without any modifications like this:

```
(echo -e 'testName\n'; cat ) | ./a.out
```

This way you ensure that your program's standard input doesn't end after what `echo` outputs. Instead, `cat` continues to supply input to your program. The source of that subsequent input is your terminal since this is where `cat` reads from.

Here's an example session:

```
bash-3.2$ cc stdin_shell.c 
bash-3.2$ (echo -e 'testName\n'; cat ) | ./a.out 
Please enter your name: warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
Hello "testName"
pwd
/home/user/stackoverflow/stdin_shell_question
ls -l
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  group  9024 Dec 14 18:53 a.out
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group   216 Dec 14 18:52 stdin_shell.c
ps -p $$
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
93759 ttys000    0:00.01 (sh)
exit

bash-3.2$
```

Note that because shell's standard input is not connected to a terminal, `sh` thinks it is not executed interactively and hence does not display the prompt. You can type your commands normally, though.

Comment: Ah.. yes you are correct, (I actually managed to find this solution before a saw your post, but thank you for putting it up here).

Answer (score 3):

Using `execve("/bin/sh", 0, 0);` is cruel and unusual punishment for the shell.  It gives it no arguments or environment at all - not even its own program name, nor even such mandatory environment variables as PATH or HOME.

Comment: well... yeah I agree completely, but this is simply used as an experiment. I would never use this in anything similar to a usable program.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure of this (the precise shell being used and the OS might throw these answers a bit; I believe that FreeBSD uses GNU `bash` by default as `/bin/sh`?), but

- `sh` may be detecting that its input is not a tty.

or

- Your version of `sh` might go into non-interactive mode like that also if called as `sh`, expecting `login` will prepend a `-` onto `argv[0]` for it. Setting up `execve ("/bin/sh", { "-sh", NULL}, NULL)` might convince it that it's being run as a login shell.